# Homepage - blank screen, Admin - The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: magento2.2.2

After changing mode Magento homepage shows blank screen, and admin - The page isn’t redirecting properly

There are no errors in reports or exception log.

In system.log:

```
Broken reference: the 'logger' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

Switched mode back - but problem remains

Also when I try enable/disable modules I got this error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException] 
The file "/composer.json" doesn't exist
```

Comment: is there any custom modules ?

Comment: yes, I disabled them and now site works.  But error with composer still  shows in console

Comment: You have to set atleast access permission to your custom module

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with magento2.2.4. Its working fine with sample data but on clean fresh magento2.2.4, it's having the same issue. any help?